# Is there any versions of NWJS and Atom-shell available for Raspbian armhf?

Tags: node.js

I contemplated the option of building an app that will run on a ARM single board computer (armv7l armhf) such as the new Raspberry Pi 2 using `nw.js` or `atom-shell`.

My first research tells me that that might not be possible. Is that a fact and what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unofficial ARM binary for NW.js here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1151#issuecomment-77812383

Comment: Please vote up the question if you found it legit! Thank you so much for finding this. I hope official release will come soon. I will try this one in the meantime. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

I have just created a repository with the node-webkit binary port that runs on Raspbian, tested and working on Raspberry Pi 1 and Raspberry Pi 3 so it is ARMv6 and ARMv7 compatible.

Here you can check it: https://github.com/jalbam/nwjs_rpi